# Is it possible to @Query two microservice databases in Java?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, netflix-zuul

I am trying to write a query where conditions in two micro-service application databases will be applied to retrieve data. Is it possible to write a `@Query` within a repository to do so, or will I need to do it from a service or any other method? With the current functions below I get an error. Any code examples or reference articles will be truly appreciated.

Below I have showed my controller function and repository query.

*Controller Function:*

```
@GetMapping("/orders/query/test/")
public List<Orders> findAllOrdersWhereCondition(){
    log.info("Start of findAllOrdersWhereCondition method");
    return repository.findAllActiveAndUnrespondedQueriesForHelp();
}
```

*Repository Functions:*

```
@Query("SELECT g FROM ORDERS g INNER JOIN operators o ON g.profileToId = o.id OR g.profileFromId = o.id WHERE g.active = true and g.responded = false AND o.operatorType = 1 ")
List<Orders> findAllActiveAndUnrespondedQueriesForHelp();
```

Comment: _"With the current functions below I get an error." Please specify the error, also what do you mean with _two micro-service application databases"_? Do you mean that `ORDERS` is in one database and `operators` is in another database? If so, what database system do you use?

Comment: From testing and further research found out NO I cannot use @query method due the fact I have two separate microservices within application with their own databases.

Answer (score 0):

Is it one service talking to two databases, or two services each talking to their own individual databases?

If it's the former, and the databases are relational and ACID, you can do a JOIN and a single query.

If it's the latter, you have to make two HTTP requests, one to each service.  They don't know about each other.  You've probably given up ACID in this case.

Comment: In this case I do have 2 separate microservices with their own databases on their own server ports. However I am using Zuul which works as a proxy between them

Comment: You have to make two different HTTP requests and process both responses in the caller.  Zuul is irrelevant.

Comment: The former depends on whether or not your database system supports cross-database joins (and if they are on the same server, or have defined linked-servers, etc).

Comment: I would argue that services should act as the gatekeepers to their databases.  There should be no access except through the services.  This is an AWS standard.  If that's not the case, services should be put in front of those data sources.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to give a correct answer without error message and entity-classes of your application. But I think, that you made a mistake in the table names in your query - if you use JPQL, you need to observe the register of entity class names writing the query. In your case it's maybe:

```
@Query("SELECT g FROM Orders g INNER JOIN Operators o ON g.profileToId = o.id OR g.profileFromId = o.id WHERE g.active = true and g.responded = false AND o.operatorType = 1 ")
List<Orders> findAllActiveAndUnrespondedQueriesForHelp();
```

If you want to make a query to a database in pure SQL, you need to set true to the field `nativeQuery`. For example:

```
@Query("SELECT g FROM Orders g INNER JOIN Operators o ON g.profileToId = o.id OR g.profileFromId = o.id WHERE g.active = true and g.responded = false AND o.operatorType = 1 ", nativeQuery = true)
List<Orders> findAllActiveAndUnrespondedQueriesForHelp();
```